# getc and fgetc not working... giving Segmentation fault

Tags: c, file, pointers

I'm trying to copy contents of one file into another. Before I finished, I wanted to print the contents out on screen to see that things are working. But they didn't.

I included...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
```

and my code is...

```
void decodeBin(char * filename){
    //opens  filename for reading and outfilename for writing
    FILE * input = fopen(filename, "r");

    char file_name[] = "";
    strcpy(file_name, filename);
    char out_file[] = "out";
    strcat(out_file, file_name);
    FILE * output = fopen(out_file, "w");


    char ch;
    if (input != NULL){
        while((ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

I looked at the other stack overflow posts, which suggested to check if file pointer is not null, which I do. What's going wrong?

Comment: Use a debugger to help you. At a minimum it will tell you immediately where the seg fault happens. And it lets you trace the program execution and examine variables. In this case your problem is that you have declared `file_name` and `out_file` to be a certain fixed size and then you try to write more than that into the buffers. In C, arrays do no automatically grow by themselves. You need to either allocate some MAX size or you need to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If `FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");` failed, `fclose(input);` will probably cause a crash.  You can only safely close an successfully opened file.  You don't actually use `output`, but neither do you check that it was successfully opened before you close it.

Comment: regarding: `FILE * input = fopen(filename, "r");`  should  be immediately followed by: `if( ! input ) { perror( "fopen for input file failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   very similar statements should follow: `FILE * output = fopen(out_file, "w");`

Comment: regarding: `char out_file[] = "out";`  This only allocates 4 characters.  However, to avoid a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, that should be similar to: char out_file[ strlen( "out ) + strlen( file_name ) + 1 ];`  Note: the +1 to allow room for the NUL terminator byte

Comment: regarding: `char file_name[] = "";` This generates a buffer of only 1 character, containing a NUL byte. So writing anything into that buffer is undefined behavior and can cause a seg fault event. Suggest something similar to: `char file_name[ strlen( filename ) +1 ];` followed by:`strcpy( file_name, filename );`

Comment: regarding: `char ch;` and `while((ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF)`  the function: `fgetc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.  And on many systems, a `char` will not recognize a EOF` (as EOF is `int` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're causing undefined behavior by writing outside the bounds of the `file_name` and `out_file` arrays. When you don't specify a size for the array, the size is determined from the string you use to initialize it. So it's equivalent to

```
char file_name[1] = "";
char out_file[4] = "out";
```

The extra byte is for the trailing null.

Since you didn't declare the arrays big enough for the strings you're copying into them, you get undefined behavior.

You need to declare the size of the arrays big enough to hold the largest possible filename. Or use `malloc()` to size it in terms of the parameters.

There's no need for the `file_name` variable, since it's just a copy of `filename`, and you can use that directly.

```
char *outfile = malloc(strlen(filename) + sizeof("out"));
sprintf(outfile, "out%s", filename);
```

Then at the end of the function, do

```
free(outfile);
```